# JUnit for Spring beans using autowire?

Tags: java, spring, junit

Here is the code:

```
public class Customer 
{
    @Autowired
    private Person person;
    //some business logic using person object
}
```

Now I need to write the jUnit test case for the Customer class, how to go about it?
Shall i use Mockito to mock the person object and then execute the business logic and if yes the how to set the mocked person object as the property of the Customer without any setter/getter?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds to me like you're overthinking it.

I would not mock a business object model; that's for interface-based classes when you don't want an integration test.

I would not inject a `Person` into a JUnit test; I'd simply call "`new`", instantiate what was appropriate for my test, and get on with it.

If your Customer has to have an instance of Person, I'd recommend constructor injection.  You can pass a mock Person that way if you must.

Comment: Unless Person is just a struct - and perhaps even if it is - mocking is a good idea. It's a unit test for Customer, right? Why would you not try to factor out the behavior of other significant classes?

Comment: I'm thinking that mocking a business object like a Person wouldn't buy me anything over and above just calling new and instantiating one.

Comment: one more thing I would like to ask is that if DAO call is taking place from an Action object, then while write junit for the action should have mock the dao call as we are writing unit testing 'cos if we don't mock DAO it would be categorized as integration test?

Comment: Yes.  Test the DAO using a database connection - it makes no sense otherwise.  But other classes that use the DAO can benefit from a mock once you're sure the DAO is sound.